# Не выводится на печать символ "\"

Tags: python

Мне нужно вывести строку в принт, в ней содержится символ слеш `"\"` . Код выполняется, но на выходе получается строка без этого символа. Есть способы вывести на принт этот символ?

```
  print('LimitedObjectId=\"0;0;0;0;0\",CtrlImsiProMode=0,NCellLayer=')
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
print('LimitedObjectId=\\"0;0;0;0;0\\",CtrlImsiProMode=0,NCellLayer=')
```

Два слэша вместо одного поставьте

Answer (score 0):

Используйте raw строку:

````
>>>print(r'LimitedObjectId=\"0;0;0;0;0\",CtrlImsiProMode=0,NCellLayer=')
LimitedObjectId=\"0;0;0;0;0\",CtrlImsiProMode=0,NCellLayer=```
````